# RFC: Chat Seminars

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Myself, [J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498/j-m) and [tb](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/t-b) came to a wonderful enlightenment on the chat recently.

A few days ago, the chat went into a deep measure theoretic discussion and a separate room was spawned to keep the main chatroom for the general chat.

So we came up with the idea of having a separate room, in which an invited speaker could give a lecture and later on answer questions. Of course this is less likely to go wonderfully smooth without in-chat $\LaTeX$ support, but there are workarounds.

The ideal is to have a weekly session. Of course this may be too much so have a lecture once every two weeks, much like a colloqium or a seminar.

I have created a separate chatroom which is a "gallery" chatroom, it means that it is read only for everyone and the speaker will be granted a voice. After the lecture will be finished we will work out a method for asking questions (perhaps in a different room) so it will not clutter the chat log.

What I would like to ask the good folks of math.SE is to come up with ways that we can make this even better.

Suggestions about how to get $\LaTeX$ work on the chat (as Jeff remarked that they do not plan on adding such support to chat) are most welcomed.

Along side a list of "What you'd like to hear". Remember that this is not a 1-1 technical hour, and should probably be similar to what you'd hear in the seminar at your local department.

Comment: You wrote: _Suggestions about how to get LATEX work on the chat are most welcome_. I've posted this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering/ at the main page. Something useful might pop-up there.

Answer (score 15):

I'm a bit skeptical.

I was present for much of the measure theory event, and it was indeed wonderful to watch. But I think what made it wonderful was that it was essentially a one-on-one tutoring session rather than a lecture. It was a *dialogue*, with lots of "do you think you get XYZ now, or should we move on to PQR?" and "wait a moment, how does UVW follow from this". That made it very effective, because the "tutor" could match the pace of the presentation *exactly* to the "student".

But I don't think that experience will transfer easily to a public lecture-and-questions format with a plenary audience. You cannot match pace that way to an audience larger than at most two or tree persons. Even if some mechanism for questions from the audience *during* the lecture was found, it would be quite random *which* members of the audience would feel comfortable interrupting with questions. (This is different from an academic colloquium, where generally a good fraction of those present *know* for certain they are the core target audience of the talk, and so feel free to ask clarifying questions).

If, as I expect, the lecture-and-question format ends up being effectively a *monologue* followed by discussion, then I have to wonder what is the point of monologuing in a chatroom, rather than send out a properly typeset pdf some time in advance and having everybody read that? A "let's all read such-and-such paper and then discuss it" event would feel more promising to me.

But perhaps that's just me. I can't fathom what the point of video lectures is either (compared to, say, prose essays), but plenty of people seem to like them just fine. There might be a market for chatroom lectures too.

Comment: +1 for expressing exactly my feelings concerning the "lectures".

Comment: Apart from people with different levels of their mathematical knowledge, we also have people from different timezones - this might be  problem, too.

Comment: The point of video lectures versus essays is the same difference between TV news and reading the newspaper. I am not a cognitive scientists, but I have heard say that *passive* (as in television, radio, etc) consumption of information engages the brain in a different way as does *active* consumption of information. That said, in the context of this question, I completely agree with you: the main advantage of the chat format is that it facilitates teaching *just at the right level of details*. When the audience size grows this becomes untenable.

Comment: It was indeed wonderful!