# The first coordinated study: calculus, with Simply Beautiful Art

Tags: discussion

Previous meta posts for background:

- [Discussion groups to assist those self-studying or enrolled students](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26862/discussion-groups-to-assist-those-self-studying-or-enrolled-students)
- [A call for volunteers - "study group" coordinators and advisors](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26864/a-call-for-volunteers-study-group-coordinators-and-advisors)

---

### Details

[SimplyBeautifulArt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/272831/simply-beautiful-art) has kindly volunteered to guide our first coordinated study, on calculus! It will be a study on basic calculus that may extend into higher-level topics. [Mithrandir24601](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19951/mithrandir24601) has also volunteered to help SimplyBeautifulArt out.

### Interested Students

Please list your names in the answer below and come into the [Calculus and Analysis chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/calculus-and-analysis), where the class will be held, so you are pingable. There will be an informational meeting held on September 9 (this Saturday) at 22:00 UTC, which you can register for [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14150/calculus-and-analysis?tab=schedule) (or you can just pop in, if you'd like). The class will meet weekly on Saturdays, also at 22:00 UTC. Feel free to come in early or late to the meetings, but it would be preferred that you join the conversation while its alive. If you don't, then the response may be late.

Due to unforeseen natural events along the Eastern coast of the US, I fear I may not be able to make it on Saturday. As such, anyone still interested in meeting Saturday may attempt to do so, though I may not be there. For the time being, please read the following chat message and stay safe.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39857462#39857462

Comment: Perhaps: Feel free to come in early or late to the meeting, but it would be preferred that you join the conversation while its alive. If you don't, then the response may be late.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt edited to include.

Comment: Can we perhaps *not* turn the meta site to announcements and polls about this project?

Comment: In relation to @Asaf's comment, I'll ask whether somebody could think of a suitable name for a tag related to "this type" of posts. (In this way, people who are not interested could at least avoid posts about this project by adding it to [ignored tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ignored-tags/info).)

Comment: I realize that you want to occasionally advertise your project, but please keep it to a minimum. It may be a good idea to only make these announcements in your project's chatroom. A possibility that occurs to me is to add the meta-tag [meta-tag:featured] to your ["main" post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26864/11619). That way it would have more exposure in main. But, 1) Only moderators can add that meta tag, 2) I won't add it without the approval of the community and my fellow moderators, 3) It should be for a limited time only lest it blocks something else with a higher priority.

Comment: @Jyrki: I think that a one time featured post wouldn't be a bad idea for something like a week or two weeks. And that after that an alternative outlet for these sort of announcements should be found. It can be the chat (or a secondary chatroom with announcements) or something like that, or even a dedicated website or something. But that featured post should cover *everything* that people would want to know, and where to find additional information.

Comment: @AsafKaragila this is closely related to M.SE. It's a community project. Why don't you want it on meta? If you don't want to read these, then don't. There are people interested, as conveyed by the votes on the other two questions as part of this. And finally, three meta posts is not a lot, and they wouldn't happen that often.

Comment: Three meta posts are a lot. Meta is not as active as the main site (and when it is, it is usually not a good sign if health for the community). And no, this is not about the website or the community. It is about some group of people, who decided to use the chat platform for some additional mathematical use. This is fine, but don't pretend this is about the community or the site.

Comment: @heather: Three posts may not be a problem. I am more worried about you announcing each and every lecture here in a different post. If the MSE University has, say, 12 courses going on concurrently, each with three lectures per week. Well, then we get 36 posts per week. And that, is a problem. Bumping a single thread with 36 updates per week is also a problem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sure, I get that. Believe me, if this gets to that point, I won't post every time a course starts or will be starting, but it's important that people notice this as it's starting out. I'm thinking about ways to announce this off-site or in a more minimized format (I'm considering one large meta post to hold all classes (past, present, and future), which would keep it to one post) but for now, I'd like this post to be reopened because it's important that, like I said, this be widely known about starting out.

Comment: So my suggested solution is that you prepare a single post in meta. There you give links to your main chatroom, possibly with a list of courses. And in your main chatroom you post the schedules. It is probably a good idea then to assign another chat room to each and every course. If you do that, then I can arrange that your MASTER post in meta gets extra visibility in Math.SE by making it featured for two weeks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have some questions; do you want to talk in chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63252/discussion-on-education-opportunities-on-mse)?

Comment: You see that pale pink (or is it beige?) box titled "FEATURED IN META". That's where a link to the main post would go. That way you get the exposure you need, but in a way that does not hog meta :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I certainly agree that too *many posts* about the same thing on meta are not good. And I get your point that there is a difference between something more closely related to SE and something which only uses chatrooms for some (albeit related) purpose. But in the past, when you had an idea on some activity to do in chat, meta seemed to be the natural place to discuss that suggestion - [RFC: Chat Seminars](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3199), (And I'll admit I am probably the most frequent poster of suggestions of the form: "Could we maybe use chat for this and that.")

Comment: @Martin: Yes, but meta a few years ago was different, and I only made that one post. So the comparison is not at all appropriate.

Comment: This type of announcement on meta, about your proposal for using a chatroom as a platform for studying calculus, after seeking no feedback about the best available calculus teacher willing to participate (willing to teach is not necessarily "able" to teach, after all), nor other volunteers, is inappropriate.  You're at a point at which suggestions should be restricted to the "Discussion on Education Opportunities on MSE" chat room, and or in the designated chat room in which your proposed event will occur.  Asaf has expressed this far better than I.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  And where are you going to find the time, apart the five chatrooms you co-own and participate in actively, your high school classes (chunk of time, time for homework too), and your work on your associate's degree (chunk of time, and the time you'll need for homework, *there*, as well), for "teaching a class", when you've never taught?

Comment: @amWhy No idea, but I assume I can at least fit in one day per week into my schedule. :-)

Comment: @MartinSleziak suggestion for tag that could help via favorites/ignores: [tag:chat-event], which is both what some other sites use to organize their chat events and the name for the SE chat feature implicated.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  FYI  Showing up one hour each week does not a good teacher make.  Talk to any teacher/professor you can to verify this.  Lesson plans, preparation each week, organization, reading/skimming through any suggested readings, etc.  Teaching requires for more investment than you've given to your chat rooms, combined.

Comment: @amWhy Very true, however, I do not consider this to be anywhere near on the par of real teaching.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Can you please explain why a chat-room event should be a "featured question on Meta?"  Sorry, chatrooms have never been (AFAIK) on topic on Meta, save for discussion about chat-jax which is used across all chat rooms.  I'm sorry, but I really do have to question your "objectivity" is this case.

Comment: @amWhy er - see all the questions under the tag labelled [tag:chat] (over 70). Chat is quite on-topic on meta. Part of me thinks you're just trying to be obstructive at this point, tbh, as I already mentioned this to you in chat. Please listen to the responses to your objections!

Comment: Well, you still should plan on preparation (before this Saturday), and before each week's meeting.  Otherwise, you will be doing nothing more than you already have done in your own Calc room, one on one, sporadic tutoring. If you can't take this upcoming role more seriously, at least to some degree, then I will be at your back all the way through.

Comment: @heather, please listen, and seriously consider, feedback regarding pitfalls, and how to avoid them.

Comment: Heather: 70 out of how many?  How many of them propose a "class"?  In any case, I am not in any way whatsoever obstructive, nor am I trying to be.  The fact that I am making clear you and @SimplyBeautifulArt are ill-prepared for anything more that a calculus chatroom (two of which already exist), is an honest, and objective assessment on my part.

Comment: @heather  you're getting uncomfortably too close to another user who promoted an even more extensive goal, in that, any one who  asks questions you don't want to address, and/or anyone who is skeptical for reasons A, B, C, whom you ignore, is therefore "obstructive."  You're going to, at one point or another, learn that you won't always be met with "Yay!   You go girl!  Go for it!".  And bottom line, I mostly fear that you are clueless as to what is really happening here.

Comment: @amWhy :-/ I do not see what such a problem is with heather's response time. It's barely been 10 minutes since heather's last comment with you, have you no patience? People have lives, they can be busy, 10 minutes is certainly too short of a time frame to expect a response.

Comment: @amWhy (responding in a backwards order) Perhaps we are insufficient for the job. But, again, I do not think you should equate this anywhere to real teaching. The more I look at it, the more I think this is merely a guided study group, and as Martin mentions someplace, there have been many such study groups, which have been successful. To add a guiding figure is all this seems to really be to me. Perhaps I've interpreted it wrong, but I do not believe we are so ill-prepared for this. Ill-prepared? Yes, but not so much so.

Comment: in response to your second to last comment: I am referring to the fact that she has failed to respond to my earlier questions.  And here, simply accused me of "trying to be obstructive at this point".  All for having asked questions, and most recently, after I commented to Jyrki (not addressing here).  Instead, she popped in to accuse me of being obstructive. That's absurd.

Comment: @amWhy I do not know what to think of that. I believe heather means to point out that you've already said all of this, and you've already had responses. Have you not thought that, perhaps, you come off sometimes as offensive and pressuring? Yes, you provide constructive advice, but it does kind of sound like you are trying to push this to a demise.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  I note the edits that you've made: deleting "class" and replacing it with "coordinated study",  and deleting, deleting  "class" and replacing it with details.  These are all points I've tried to address with heather, but told "I should know that class doesn't mean class, and that teacher doesn't mean teacher, etc.  I have no objection to being honest and upfront.  Thank you.

Comment: @amWhy okay, look, I'm listening to your feedback. I agree with Simply's edits. I just don't have all eternity to continue internet arguments with people! You're being argumentative, not listening to my responses, and so forth. And heck, yes, I know that all my proposals will be met with "you go girl" - it's offensive that you think I think that. I have failed before, quite miserably, and I'm working to make sure that this isn't one of those failures. Please listen to responses and be willing to have a reasoned, *two-sided* discussion, or realize that I just can't respond to every comment.

Comment: @amWhy also if you want to keep discussing this, perhaps we should go into chat so we don't "hijack meta" as you seem to think I'm doing.

Comment: @amWhy Well, English sucks. People don't see eye to eye on what words mean when mushed together certain ways. You just can't help it if someone believes certain words play a different effect than your perspective.

Comment: My only comment here, today, @SimplyBeautifulArt, was to Jyriki. Period, It was heather that came running over to "scold me" and accuse me of trying to be "obstructive".  Because I addressed Jyriki with what I believe is a valid question? No, I've not had honest responses, only shaming responses, and responses that accuse me of being obstructive for the mere fact that I've asked legitimate questions.  Dismissive responses, responses to the effect, "yes, I said X, but we all know it's really Y. etc"

Comment: Address your comment, @SimplyBeautifulArt, to heather, as well!

Comment: @heather  If you are unwilling to express more honestly what to expect at the "event" scheduled for Saturday, in this meta post about that event, then my comments belong here.  You seemed to have demurred to Simply's edits to your post, which were likely made to address concerns I had already addressed.  All I have asked is for you and those participating in this "project" to be honest. Thankyou.

Comment: @amWhy fwiw I'm reading the whole comment thread. And can I not respond to an objection you raised? Jyrki can respond as well if he/she would like. Yes, I agree with Simply's edits, I just haven't had time due to personal things I've had to do. Also, before you make me out as some sort of insulting jerk, please reread through your comments to me. You're coming across as quite demanding, offensive, and so forth. This may not be what you intended, but as Simply said, English sucks.

Comment: And also, I think I've expressed quite clearly what is going to happen at the event on Saturday - the coordinated study's book/syllabus/etc will be discussed. Questions of Simply can also be asked.

Comment: @amWhy Well, I'm not quite sure what the issue really is, but I think heather's response to you was well suited and quite related, despite your message being directed to Jyriki. It's not like Jyriki can't respond back to you, and it makes a difference that heather as well as others have previously discussed whether or not chat is an available topic for meta.

Comment: And I don't quite know what to make of your response to heather from there. You note that there are only 70 chat questions. It is not a matter of how many, it is a matter of whether or not these sorts are valid questions.  You then ask how many concern classes. My response to that is hopefully none, else this should likely be closed as a dupe. New questions should be invited.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt you are making this more than what I said.  How often do users get to ask a moderator, who obliges, to feature their meta post within "featured meta posts"?  That was the point of my comment to Jyrki.  What's happened since is another "distress call" to which her knights reply to fight off dragons, and such.  Good night.

Comment: @amWhy And perhaps you make more of what heather says than what's there. From the way I see it, Jyriki suggested using the featured feature, to which heather though was possibly a good idea. Anyways, good night to you as well, I need sleep.

Comment: @heather I'm afraid the responses (from the people not involved) to my suggestion to use the [meta-tag:featured] meta tag for this have been mostly negative. Here Asaf gave lukewarm support (possibly reading it the way it was intended - as a means of avoiding other meta-clutter). For her part amWhy seems to be skeptical. I polled two fellow diamond mods: one wants to see the concept of MSEU crash and burn, the other thought that "featuring" it amounts to officially condoning the attempt. Doesn't look too good, does it?

Comment: (cont'd) Judging from what I see here it's not clear that your plans are well developed yet. It may work out if you locate enough good people. For my part you are welcome to try and develop this further - wishing you luck. But it sounds to me that at the moment you have a study group that wishes to meet regularly, and is now assigning "a first speaker". My suggestion would be that you *Go with that and see if it evolves naturally into something bigger*. Baby steps.

Comment: @Jyrki: I did read your suggestion as intended, because as someone who is not an idealist 20-something anymore, I know that sometimes you need to see things crash and burnt before you understand that trying to list just a small piece of ice from the water means dragging a huge iceberg with it. I spoke against the blog, and I watched it die from lack of participation; and I spoke against these ideas, and we will watch them crash and burn. But for that, they need to first be half-assed built and covered with gasoline. Which is why I was lukewarm to allow one meta thread. However, [...]

Comment: [...] I do understand why someone would think that a featured thread on meta is somewhat of an official support of the idea. And I do agree that in this case, either thorough clarification are needed, or giving up on the idea. And because history had taught us that there are never enough clarification, I concede that this is a point I have not thought when I first read your suggestion, and that it is a good point. So I no longer think it would be a good idea.

Comment: Would anyone rather have the calculus group be in [my personal chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54911/simply-beautiful-arts-realm-of-calculus-and-analysis)? Particularly, I don't think the people who visit my chat will be bothered much by it, and I'm not the most familiar with the calculus and analysis room.

Comment: Is this going to be a rigorous approach over calculus, i.e. real analysis or a more computational one?

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov As planned, we will take a less rigorous approach, but it may depend on who I'm looking at. Having had contact with heather, for example, she does not seem to know much calculus at all, so it may be hard to apply rigor as you'd expect from real analysis courses.

Answer (score -1):

### Interested Students

- [heather](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/352306/heather) - I have a (very) little bit of experience with single-variable calculus. I've already taken highschool algebra and geometry at school.
- [A-B](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/312097/a-b) - Ping me.
- [Donald](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/404247/donald-splutterwit) - ...

Comment: Those who are interested in Saturday's event should read this chat message: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39857462#39857462